# Tokens retrieval from an Exchange ETH address

Tags: transactions, wallets

I invested in an ICO and in return they sent me the Tokens they generated using ETH protocols, but unfortunately I used an Exchange [koinex.in] ETH Wallet Address as mentioned below:

https://etherscan.io/token/0xe83e098eedb43b33d340d4757529e5a2c4ee3230?a=0x804c868b5fd92ea2ec1d9160e1652cac61fd332d

My Exchange doesn't provide any Priv Key and Token distributor says he can't help me in it, therefore is there any possible way or method that I can be able to retrieve my "BOON" tokens to any other Private/Personal ETH Address Wallet. Please help me, I'd greatly appreciate this.

Regards,
Sahil Sehgal

Answer (score 1):

Your only option is to contact the exchange. In theory they have the tokens but possibly they are not willing to go through the trouble of getting them sent to your wallet address. I wouldn't blame them if they refuse - it might be quite a hassle to get the tokens from their own wallets (and also a security risk).